# What is the maximum size of a message in the Cast SDK?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to figure out what the maximum size of a message between sender and receiver is. In certain cases in my app I need to send fairly large messages.

I know there is a maximum size, and so I would need to send my message in separate parts. But other than for Media Playback messages, I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that states the max amount of bytes a message can be.

The Media messages docs explain that in the media namespace "the transport message maximum size is currently 64 KBytes." https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages

Is this applicable to messages in any namespace as well, or do they have different restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should assume the 64K size applies to all messages on all namespaces.

Comment: By the way, I am not aware of the use case you have but the channel built for various namespaces is mostly considered a control channel, to be used for messages with small payload so can you elaborate why you'd need to send a large payload?

Comment: I am the dev for Dashboard Cast : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rir.dashboardcast&hl=en

Why I need to send large messages is for the user's calendar events. I am getting the user's events from an Android device, and then compiling them to a JSON array and sending that off. However, if the user has too many events, the message doesn't seem to be getting sent, which I am assuming is because the message is too large. I was going to try to split the message into separate parts and send them individually to the receiver. Do you suggest there a better way to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: I imagine the Android app is getting the calendar data from the cloud so you may consider the possibility of having the receiver fetch the calendar data directly from the cloud, if possible (the android app can pass the auth token or whatever else it needs to the receiver for it to communicate with the calendar backend directly). This way, you won't have the issue you're running into. That's just a suggestion, not knowing the details of your situation.

Comment: That is the method I am using for all my other services. But for the calendar, I am using the [CalendarProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) since it provides a simple way for me to get the user's calendar data without having to manage all their various calendar accounts, it does the heavy lifting for me. So my best option is to get the data straight from the device. If you can suggest of a better method to send that data to the receiver than split messages, I am all for it.

Comment: One alternative is the following: when your phone is ready to send the data to your receiver, your phone app can start a local web server and send a short message to your receiver with the port/url of the server (can be set random;y each time) and then your receiver can use a web call to get the data from your phone in one http call. Not sure if that would be easier or not for you.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm not familiar with local web servers. Using one would also allow me to serve up local content if I am not mistaken? Would you be able to share any documentation or point me in the right direction as to how I could implement a local web server in my app? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be able to use a project like this: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd, I am sure there are other options if you don't want to build one yourself.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!